# Django save multiple data with same form - different data for different users

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-forms, multiple-databases, create-view

Now I have a model called Score, whose forms.py as below, I would like to create different score for different users once, now I only can create a score for a user one by by, and I need to create many times, is there a easy way to create score for users just once? Thank you so much for any advice.

```
class Score(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0,)
    pass_score = models.FloatField(default=0,)

class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestScore
        fields = ('test', 'user', 'score', 'pass_score')
```

Comment: Can you clarify why the model is Score but the ModelForm is derived from TestScore?  And I think what you want is a form with each user in the system and space for their score for a particular test, is that correct?

Comment: Hi, I pasted a wrong name of  TestScore, already updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to hit url like `/all_users/test1/`

and get a set of forms (each row is a form) like this:

```
|user|test1 score |
| u1 | 80%        |
| u2 | 72%        |
| u3 | __         |
```

then what you want is a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) or, even closer to what you're doing, a [modelFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: @eyllanesc  Hi, I read those documentations and tutorials, most of them are about `updating or changing`, there is nothing about creating, could you please tell me how to use them in `creating` projects? not changing or updating, thanks

Comment: @Atcrank  Hi, I read those documentations and tutorials, most of them are about updating or changing, there is nothing about creating, could you please tell me how to use them in creating projects? not changing or updating, thanks